# How do I confirm the data queried is displayed correctly using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I am searching in a field and would like to know if the search has displayed the correct queried search in the grid?

The grid has no element ID so finding it difficult to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use x path to find it. Say you are searching for foo and you know foo will be in the grid:

xpath

```
//*[contains(text(), 'foo')]
```

python

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'foo')]")
```

Comment: I search the following using your above suggestion:

CasePresent = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'C00024853')]")
        print(CasePresent)

I get the following on the output console...
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="526bc8da-8a6d-44eb-8c15-382ecc0da0c2", element="8af59cd2-3dd0-45a3-9f97-68e7b2aeab66")>

Comment: Hi @redp I just realised that it is the xpath, what I would like is the actual content of the xpath i.e. in my case "C00024853"

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'foo')]").text`

Comment: that should return the text

Comment: Thanks that helped @redp

Comment: Hi @redp
would you know how to male it read the exact text?
(I have tried replacing CONTAINS with SPAN, and receive an error)

Comment: can you provide an example

Comment: CasePresent = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[Contains(text(), 'C00024853')]").text

If there is any other text present or any values missing then the the user is notified and the script is marked as failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851682/assert-verifyelementpresent-with-python-and-webdriver, this may help you out