# Authorization exception with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I'm having fun with Python and Selenium and have one question. How to handle an error message in case I provided wrong credentials during authorization.

From the code you can see that at the moment I'm just expecting to see next page after login and return authorization error if it won't popup in 8 seconds. To me it is quite lame and would be nice to handle login fail message.

There is a part of my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import sys
import urllib.request



if urllib.request.Request('https://url.i.want/to/open'): #check if it is reachable and open in positive response

driver = webdriver.Firefox (executable_path='path/to/webdriver')
driver.get('https://open.url/with/browser')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)


#Login page information. Contains Account Name, Username and Password
AccountName = driver.find_element_by_id('account')
AccountName.send_keys('accountname')
Login = driver.find_element_by_id('login')
Login.send_keys('login')
Password = driver.find_element_by_id('pw')
Password.send_keys('password')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#login_btn').click()

time.sleep(8) #Time to login (Not very elegant but ok for prototype)

try:
    #close pop-up infomation window
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('some_popup_window').click()
except:
    print('Please check login credentials')
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't user `time.sleep()` check the implicit and explicit waits from here : [Wait methods for python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Then to handle error messages try to assert that : [Assert/VerifyElementPresent with Python and WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851682/assert-verifyelementpresent-with-python-and-webdriver)

**For addition, your code also has not any assertions, try to add assertion after every action to validate your tests.**

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and link for extra documentation. Unfortunately it didn't answer the question I asked. I need to handle message from browser in case I provided wrong login credentials. Browser shows 'Incorrect login or user name' and I need to catch it with webdriver.

Comment: Try to catch it with if(driver.find_element_by_link_text('incorrect login or user name')) then you can do whatever you want inside that If statement. @GRinch

Comment: That is good point. Error message not a link but I can search if there is a text on page. Thanks

Comment: So you can accept the answer for closing your issue. @GRinch

Comment: Wanted to test it first. Tested and confirmed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

use driver.getTitle() method and compare it with the page title after you login with the expected title of the page,this way you can ensure you have logged in to your application.